# I have 2 names. Which is correct? He knows me as Sam or He knows me by Sam?

Tags: grammar

I have a native name and English name.

I want to explain that this particular person calls me Sam instead of the other name.

Which one of the following is correct way of saying it ?

He knows me as Sam. or He knows me by Sam ?

Thanks

Comment: "He knows me by Sam" sounds weird. I would say "He _knows me as_ Sam" or "He _calls me by_ Sam".

Comment: I concur. I'd always use "as".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is done both ways. "By Sam" unambiguously refers to your name. "As Sam" can mean the same, but can have a second meaning.

In the case of a person who has several persona's, "as Sam" could refer to a specific persona, identity, or character role.  For example, if a person is working undercover under a false identity, "as Sam" could refer to that identity.  The same could apply to an actor who is typecast. William Shatner was long "known as" Captain Kirk.